# RSpec: How to find out where the database is being hit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm using *rspec* and *factory_girl* to test my *ActiveRecord* models which have performance problems somewhere. Therefore I create a list of models using `build_stubbed`.

```
stubbed_model.some_models = build_stubbed_list(:some_model, 50)
```

This complains about the database being hit

```
RuntimeError:
  stubbed models are not allowed to access the database - SomeModel#save({:validate=>true})
```

This is actually ok for me since it indicates exactly the problems I'm searching for.

**But:** How can I find out where the database is being hit? Is there a possibility to tell *rspec* that it should tell me more? The `-b, --backtrace` option doesn't help since it shows only *rspec* and *ActiveRecord* magic.

**Update:**
I found out that not building is the problem but the assignment to the `has_many` relation field `stubbed_model.some_models`. So `--backtrace` actually showed the relevant information to me.

Comment: you probably have `SomeModel#save({:validate=>true})` in your model code and you hit the original method which creates, and that caused it. I think you need to stub out that model.

Answer (score 1):

In the future, you could run your spec suite with the `-p` flag, this will add profiling to your output and show you which specs run the slowest.

From `rspec --help`:

```
    -p, --[no-]profile [COUNT]       Enable profiling of examples and list the slowest examples (default: 10).
```